# MQTT vs Tinkerkit sensor Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, communication

I'm working with this http://knolleary.net/arduino-client-for-mqtt/. I'm using Arduino Uno + Ethernet shield + Tinkerkit Shield. But, if i have only Arduino Uno + Ethernet Shield, i can connect my arduino with MQTT and make publish/subscribe, but, when i put the tinkerkit shield, i lost the connection and i cannot connect any more. Any idea? Tinkerkit sensor shield is incompatible with mqtt?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in wiring. Ethernet shield is using SPI communication, it requires pins: `SPI: 10 (SS), 11 (MOSI), 12 (MISO), 13 (SCK)`. Those pins must be left for the Ethernet shield. Information is from [Arduino Uno description](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno).

Does your Arduino communicates with you after you plug-in Tinkerkit? If not, maybe you have a short in Tinkerkit shield.

Comment: The problem was that. Thank you so much. I'm with one led plug in 10.